# AlarmManager not scheduling task at given time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am trying to do some task at some specific time inserted by user. I have two classes.

**1. AddTiminigs

   2. TimeReceiver**

In `OnCreate` of "`AddTimings`, I m doing something like this:

```
manager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent alarmIntent_on = new Intent(getActivity(), MuteMeReceiver.class);
alarmIntent_on.putExtra("id", MUTE_ON);
pendingIntent_on = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MUTE_ON, alarmIntent_on, 0);
```

Then, on some action, i m doing this :

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  startTimeInMilis,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent_on);
```

And Here is my "`TimeReceiver`":

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent incomingPendingIntent) {

    muteStatus = incomingPendingIntent.getIntExtra("id", AddTimeFragment.MUTE_ON);

    if(muteStatus == AddTimeFragment.MUTE_ON){

        Toast.makeText(context, "GENERAL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

The Problem is that very after adding the time, it doesn't bother what the start time is, it just goes to receiver and not doing the task on the time i mentioned. The timing is in miliseconds, which is ok.

**EDIT:** 
I am using TimePicker for starttime. Here is my code:

```
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

  private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listenerForStartTime =new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

            if(selectedHour < 12) {
                am_pm = "AM";
            } else {
                am_pm = "PM";
            }

            startTimeInMilis = (selectedMinute * 60 + selectedHour * 60 * 60) * 1000;

        }
    };
```

Comment: have You added the time in milliseconds from a date? What I mean is, have You for example made an Calendar Instance, give time to it and then get the date as milliseconds? How is Your startTimeInMillis calculation?

Comment: Also for KitKat alarm delivery is inexact. the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, let me share code for time.

Comment: This might be the case, setRepeating is inexact [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,long,long,android.app.PendingIntent). So try to put some larger time period in startTimeInMilis and check.

Comment: @Chitrang, So what u saying is that i should use `setInexactRepeating` instead of `setRepeating`??

Comment: @Ali what time duration you have set? And can you check same with set (int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation) method, please.

Comment: At TimePciker, i am ,say, picking 4.30Pm, and then i m converting it which is ok

Comment: @Chitrang, sorry i didnt get you first, I need time interval at daily routine.

Comment: Ok I got your point, you need to add hours to current time,

startTimeInMilis = System.currentTimeMillis() + (selectedMinute * 60 + selectedHour * 60 * 60) * 1000;

Comment: Thnx alot @Chitrang, you reached exactly where i was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `listenerForStartTime` code as below. You are giving start time wrongly. you should not give remaining time. you should give exact time.

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listenerForStartTime =new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

        if(selectedHour < 12) {
            am_pm = "AM";
        } else {
            am_pm = "PM";
        }
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
        startTimeInMilis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
};
```